# Nhibernate QueryOver Project enum description to string

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Let`s say we have the following query using Nhibernate:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<TenantOrder>(() => tenantOrderAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => tenantOrderAlias.Tenant, () => tenantAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => tenantAlias.Building, () => buildingAlias)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(x => tenantOrderAlias.Id.OrderId).IsLike(order.Id);

query.Select(
    Projections.Property(() => tenantAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => tenantDto.Id),
    Projections.Property(() => tenantAlias.TenantNr).WithAlias(() => tenantDto.TenantNr),
    Projections.Property(() => buildingAlias.BuildingNr).WithAlias(() => tenantDto.BuildingNr),
    Projections.Property(() => tenantAlias.Floor).WithAlias(() => tenantDto.Floor),
    Projections.Property(() => tenantOrderAlias.InstallationStatus).WithAlias(() => tenantDto.InstallationStatusName //?   ));
```

We want to process InstallationStatus (type enum) from tenantOrderalias to InstallationStatusName (property of type string from tenantDto). The structure of the enum looks like below :

```
public enum TenantInstallationStatusEnum
{
    [StringEnum("MS3_TenantInstallationStatus_TS0")]
    TS0,//open
    [StringEnum("MS3_TenantInstallationStatus_TS2")]
    TS2,//abgelesen
}
```

We want to get the description of the enum and place it to *tenantDto.InstallationStatusName*. Is this possible using `QueryOver` or `ICriteria` ?
We cannot find any post about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we can *project* only stuff which exists in a DB side or is passed as a "formula". So, we can convert the status into some conditional statement like this:

```
// this projection
Projections
    .Property(() => tenantOrderAlias.InstallationStatus)
    .WithAlias(() => tenantDto.InstallationStatusName //?   ));

// could be converted into string values with this statement
Projections
    .Conditional(
        Restrictions.Where<TenantOrder>(to => 
            to.InstallationStatus == TenantInstallationStatusEnum.TS0),
        Projections.Constant("MS3_TenantInstallationStatus_TS0"),
        Projections.Constant("MS3_TenantInstallationStatus_TS2")
    ).WithAlias(() => tenantOrderAlias.InstallationStatusName)
);
```

Conditional could be even nested... but at the end it could be a bit more challenging.

But, maybe more easier in fact, would be to process this conversion ex-post, in C#, on the app side...

Comment: Good answer, I'd recommend doing it on the C# side as well